Endomorphisms of a direct sum of abelian groups.
Let $I$ be a non-empty set and let $(A_i,+_i,0_i)$ for $i\in I$ be an abelian group, such that $Hom(A_i,A_j)=0$ for $i,j\in I, i\neq j$. Then $f$ is an endomorphism of a group $A=\bigoplus_{i\in I}{A_i}$ if and only if for every $i\in I$ there exists an endomorphism $f_i$ of a group $A_i$, such that $f(x)=(f_i(x_i))_{i\in I}$ for every $x=(x_i)_{i\in I}\in A$.
This theorem is quite obvious and its proof is straightforward. My complete proof is quite long, however - I am not a specialist in Abelian group theory. I have not found proof of this statement in the books available to me (Fuchs, Robinson). Does anyone of you know any textbook/monograph/article that I can refer to to avoid writing a long proof?

Why would you want to cite anything for this? It is rather obvious. Here's a two-sentence proof: "Write $f$ as a matrix $M = (f_i({{-}})j){i, j}$, i.e $M_{i, j} = \mathrm{pr}j \circ f_i \colon A^i \to A^j$ for fixed $i, j$. By assumption $M{i, j} = 0$ for $i \neq j$, whence $M$ is diagonal and $f(x) = (f_i(x_i))_{i \in I}$ Q.E.D."

I assume that you ask about "$\Rightarrow$" implication, because the other direction is quite straight forward.
Let $f:A\to A$ be an endomorphism. For any $i\in I$ consider the standard embedding
$$e_i:A_i\to A$$
$$e_i(x)_j=\begin{cases}
x &\text{if }i=j \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
and the standard projection $\pi_i:A\to A_i$.
For $i,j\in I$ define
$$F_{i,j}:A_i\to A_j$$
$$F_{i,j}(x)=\pi_j\circ f\circ e_i(x)$$
Each $F_{i,j}$ is of course a homomorphism as a composition of homomorphisms.
Furthermore every element $x\in A=\bigoplus A_i$ can be written as
$$x=\sum_{j\in I} e_j(x_j)$$
While technically this is an infinite sum, in fact it is finite because all but finitely many $x_j$ are equal to $0$. With this we have
$$f(x)=f\big(\sum_{j\in I} e_j(x_j)\big)=\sum_{j\in I}f\circ e_j(x_j)$$
This is an element of $\bigoplus A_i$, and so we can ask: what is its $i$-th coordinate? It is of course equal to $\pi_i\big(f(x)\big)$, and then
$$\pi_i\big(f(x)\big)=\sum_{j\in I}\pi_i\circ f\circ e_j(x_j)=\sum_{j\in I} F_{i,j}(x_j)=F_{i,i}(x_i)$$
The final equality follows from our "$Hom$ assumption", because $F_{i,j}=0$ for $i\neq j$.
What we've shown is that $i$-th coordinate of $f(x)$ is equal to $F_{i,i}(x_i)$, which completes the proof. $\Box$
In fact more can be said. By carefully following this proof we can additionally show that the mapping $f\mapsto (F_{i,i})_{i\in I}$ defines a ring isomorphism $End\big(\bigoplus_{i\in I} A_i\big)\simeq \prod_{i\in I}End(A_i)$.
